# Adding a fade in and a fade out jQuery animation for a div which displays block and none according to a body class?

Tags: jquery, css

Basically, when there are search results the body gets a class called `.have-results`.
When there are not results (`body` with no classes) I have a div that display instead of the search results:

```
body {
    .pointer {
        display: block;
    }
    #results-number {
        display: none;
    }
}

body.have-results {
    .pointer {
        display: none !important;
    }
    #results-number {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

I would like that div to appear in a fade in animation and disappear in a fade out animation. How can I accomplish this with this existing css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that you have a problem with the important style for this block.

Put this code after search results intialization:

```
if ($('body').hasClass('have-results')) {
  $('.pointer').fadeOut();
}
else {
  $('.pointer').css({display:'block !important', opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);
}
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/AMM2N/1/

Comment: Hey it works but for some reason sometimes the opacity stays in 0.355985. This is the site: http://www.foodjing.com/ (without this code).

Comment: Something probably terminates the opacity. I don't know what exactly but you can put some alert in animation callback and see if animation at least finished.

Comment: an alert is called but afte that, the div disappears completely.

Comment: try to set `$(this).css({opacity:1});` in the callback to override not finished animation. But it's workaround and probably sometimes user will not see smooth animation as it should be.

Comment: Sorry, where should I put that `$this`?